# Probability of someone having another suit of cards

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A funny thing happened this weekend during a game of Oh Hell.  For those of you who don't know the rules, the important part of this question is that I was in a situation where I needed at least one other person to have a diamond.

For those of you who know the rules, I had a 2 of Diamonds and Diamonds were the trump suit.  I bet that I wouldn't take the hand because surely someone else must have a diamond.

The situation was as follows:

1. 7 people playing, including myself.
2. Everyone had two cards, thereby having fourteen cards out of the 52 to be in play.  The rest are id a discard pile, never to be touched during the round.
3. I had one diamond, the two.  My other card was not a diamond.

So, I bet someone would take this hand because there must have been another diamond out there.  My gut feeling was that the odds were not as bad as intuition might lead one to believe, and based on another player's reaction to his own cards, I was willing to take the chance.

I was wrong.  No one else had a diamond.  Later that evening, I tried to work out exactly what the probability was of someone else having a diamond.

I approached this problem as what is the probability of having no other diamonds in the other players' hands.  Total sample space as  ${52 \choose 14}$  This was the combinations of all the cards in play.  I thought the event space would be represented by ${39 \choose 12}$  The twelve represents the cards in the other players' hands.

Working this out, I got a small probability that no one else had a diamond.  Something like 0.3%.  Did I set this problem up correctly or did I just get screwed by luck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Given that you have one diamond and one non-diamond*, the chance that no one else has a diamond is $$\frac{\binom{52-2-12}{12}}{\binom{52-2}{12}}=\frac{\binom{38}{12}}{\binom{50}{12}}\approx2.23\%$$ so your calculation is not quite right. Still, yeah, you got screwed by some bad luck. I would always assume someone else had a diamond in that situation.

Comment: In other words, ${52-2-12}\choose 12$ is the same number of ways to pick 12 cards out of a deck of 50 cards after someone took the rest of the diamonds (12 cards) out of the deck.

Comment: This is great.  Thanks to both of you.

In these types of probability questions, must the "x" part of choose x from y, in this case, 12, be the same for the numerator and denominator?  That's the part I was stumbling over.